# In abstract factory pattern the main abstract factory class, Does it always have to be an abstract class?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, software-design

All the example i see of **Abstract factory Pattern** They use an abstract class to give the Abstraction for factories.
Is it always required to use `abstract class`?

Given the circumstances we can happily  use **Interface**.
If we use **interface** does it going to violate the Design principle?

Example I was Reading

[Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm)
[oodesign](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm)

Comment: using an Interface is as good as using an abstract class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Abstract Factory use abstract class instead of interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840227/why-does-abstract-factory-use-abstract-class-instead-of-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required to use an `abstract class` for a factory. It mainly depends on the complexity of the objects you want to create and how much code you can re-use among factories.

The example you link to is somewhat contrived to demonstrate the use of the abstract factory pattern. The example creates an abstract factory (the 'interface' of the factory) which is then extended with a `ShapeFactory` and a `ColorFactory`. The concrete `ShapeFactory` returns null when `getColor()` is called and vice versa. This is a violation of the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Instead I would suggest this design to show that you don't always need an abstract factory, but can use a simpler [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) as well.

```
public interface Shape {
    void Draw();
}

public class Square : Shape {
    public void Draw() { //... }
}

public class Circle : Shape {
    public void Draw() { //... }
}

public enum ShapeType {
    Square,
    Circle
}

public class ShapeFactory {
    public Shape CreateShape(ShapeType type) {
        switch (type) {
            case ShapeType.Square:
                return new Square();
            case ShapeType.Circle:
                return new Circle();
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unsupported ShapeType: " + type);
        }
    }
}
```

Use the concrete ShapeFactory like this:

```
var factory = new ShapeFactory();
var circle = factory.CreateShape(ShapeType.Circle);
```

**Edit:** Just to nitpick... In an abstract factory pattern, the base factory would always be abstract. This is because the base class (or interface) it would create isn't usable in itself. In reality you could work with a `Circle` or `Square`, but not with a `Shape`. That doesn't mean that your code can't deal with shapes in general.

Answer (score 1):

`Interfaces` and their methods are implicitly `abstract` so it's totally ok to use `interface` instead of `abstract cass`, but in order to mantain the abstract Design you must implement one of both...

Answer (score 0):

1.Factory is an abstract class.
2.Factory can create any subclass of an interface or abstract class.
3.The factory method return type is an interface or abstract class.

Comment: I am sorry I dont understand answer. Could you please elaborate?